Figuring out how to get a function matching enum and union of key types to fail if not set or doesn't match
This situation has arisen from the intersection of libraries, so our hands are a bit tied. This is just a reproduction, though the types should be accurate.
I have two enum-like types from two sources as so:
enum EnumFromSource1 {
  KEY1 = 'KEY1',
  KEY2 = 'KEY2',
  KEY3 = 'KEY3',
}

type EnumKeysUnionFromSource2 = 'KEY1' | 'KEY2' | 'KEY3'; 

Important: you can assume that the enum is defined such that the keys and values are always equal, and defined as KEY = 'KEY'
These are supposed to be the same, but can occasionally drift apart, which is what I want to detect in the following:
function theyShouldMatch<???>(enum: ???): T {}

This is only very rough, but basically I want to have to write theyShouldMatch<EnumKeysUnionFromSource2>(EnumFromSource1) (something including typeof EnumFromSource1 would be totally fine too, eg theyShouldMatch<typeof EnumFromSource1, EnumKeysUnionFromSource2>(EnumFromSource1)) such that it would throw a compiler error if the keys didn't match, eg if at some point they became the following:
enum EnumFromSource1 {
  KEY1 = 'KEY1',
  KEY2 = 'KEY2',
  KEY3 = 'KEY3',
  KEY4 = 'KEY4',
}

type EnumKeysUnionFromSource2 = 'KEY1' | 'KEY2' | 'KEY3'; 

(or the flip where EnumKeysUnionFromSource2 has an extra value not in the enum).
Any advice? If one has to be considered the "source of truth" it should be EnumKeysUnionFromSource2
Edit: from the comments, here is an example of a function I'd like to make type safe (again, watered down from more complex examples). any function is fine, this is just to have an example. also note that the typing of the Enum can be changed, it doesn't have to be Enum[keyof Enum], this is just what we were able to get working.
type Serde<T> = {
  serialize: (v: T) => string;
  deserialize: (v: string) => T;
};

function enumSerde<???>(
  e: Enum,
): Serde<Enum[keyof Enum]> {
  return {
    serialize: (x: Enum[keyof Enum]): string => x.toString(),
    deserialize: (x: string) => e[x as keyof Enum],
  };
}

// invocation
const serde = enumSerde<typeof EnumFromSource1, EnumFromSource2>(EnumFromSource1);

and ideally given the above, the following would fail
enum EnumFromSource1_bad1 {
  KEY1 = 'KEY1',
  KEY2 = 'KEY2',
  KEY3 = 'KEY3',
  BAD = 'BAD'
}

enum EnumFromSource1_bad2 {
  KEY1 = 'KEY1',
  KEY2 = 'KEY2',
}

// should fail at compile time
enumSerde<typeof EnumFromSource1_bad1, EnumFromSource2>(EnumFromSource1_bad1);
enumSerde<typeof EnumFromSource1_bad2, EnumFromSource2>(EnumFromSource1_bad2);


Are we matching the keys or the values here? you're using the word "key" a bunch of places and I'm not sure what to do if your enum is like enum X {KEY5 = "KEY6"}.

see prev comment... like, you can certainly compare things and get compiler errors if they don't match, as shown in this playground link, but I don't understand if we care about the enum keys or the enum values or somehow both. Please [edit] to clarify.

ah, good question! I just edited for clarity. it can be either (I would welcome advise as to which to prefer?) because the style guide for the enums we use is always to have KEY=VALUE, particularly because of this issue ("keys? values? make them the same and avoid a lot of headaches"). so if leveraging that makes things easier, you definitely can. if there's a best practice, that's welcome too!

• I don't know if there's a "best practice". My opinion is that enums are more trouble than they're worth and you can just use a union of literals. If it's important that the keys and values are equal all that means (in my opinion) is that enums aren't really helping you. That's off topic here, though. • Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

yes, that approach misses my needs, thank you! an answer would be great. the one thing missing is what's the best way to get the type checking that Same allows to work with a method like doesActualThings<T, U>(enum: T)...I've tried a couple approaches but imagine you will know of a better one

“that approach misses my needs” I’m hoping that’s a typo. So you actually want to couple the type check with a function call even though a function call isn’t necessary? I can probably write that but I’m not sure what to do, especially if you don’t care if the input is an enum value or an enum object. What “actual things” is it doing? That will drive what the input type needs to be

that was a typo, I had just woken up. I mean "that approach meets my needs." I'll edit the question to have an example function

ok, I added a function that hopefully will give you something to go off of. thank you for your help!

Okay, please take a look at this playground link, test it out, and let me know if that works for you. If so I'll write up an answer.

that is almost perfect, but I think there is one lingering error, which is if you just don't call it with anything eg enumSerde(someEnum) it doesn't throw an error. not sure if there's a way to force typescript to error if you don't provide something there? otherwise the answer is perfect and is what I was looking for! edit: it looks like adding = never to the type parameters may be enough to create an error
